# What is the appropriate alt tag for an image where we only know that it was uploaded by a user?

Tags: html, accessibility, alt

On our site we have a case where we show a list of images that have been uploaded by various users of a product we sell. We don't have any context as to what the image is of other than the product we're selling on the page. Here's the various options we've discussed:

1. Empty alt tag `alt=""`. Screen readers would read nothing.
2. Alt tag saying it was user uploaded `alt="customer uploaded content"`. This would repeat the same thing for every image.
3. Same thing as (2) but instead giving an index for the image to show the number of them there are `alt='${index} customer uploaded content'`.
4. Omit the alt attribute entirely.

I am less concerned about SEO in this specific case than I am accessibility. I'm not sure what the best practice is and if having screen readers read out repetitive content could potentially be bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [specification has exhaustive information about the `alt` attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#alt) including a section [Images whose contents are not known](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#unknown-images):

> In some unfortunate cases, there might be no alternative text available at all, […] because the page is being generated by a script using user-provided images where the user did not provide suitable or usable alternative text (e.g. photograph sharing sites) […]
>
> In such cases, the `alt` attribute may be omitted, but one of the
> following conditions must be met as well:
>
> - The `img` element is in a `figure` element that contains a `figcaption` element that contains content other than inter-element whitespace, and, ignoring the `figcaption` element and its descendants, the `figure` element has no flow content descendants other than inter-element whitespace and the `img` element.
> - The `title` attribute is present and has a non-empty value.

(snip)

> A photo on a photo-sharing site, if the site received the image with no metadata other than the caption, could be marked up as follows:

```html
<figure>
  <img src="1100670787_6a7c664aef.jpg">
  <figcaption>Bubbles traveled everywhere with us.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

> It would be better, however, if a detailed description of the important parts of the image obtained from the user and included on the page.

---

> I am less concerned about SEO in this specific case than I am accessibility. I'm not sure what the best practice is and if having screen readers read out repetitive content could potentially be bad.

Make it easy for screen reader users to skip the section. Make use of [`<section>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section) and `<h1>` and friends. That way when they get the announcement "Section: Customer photos", they can skip to the next heading.

#### Best Practice: ATAG

The best practice would be to acknowledge that your site is an *authoring tool*, as it allows creating content, and to conform to the [Authoring Tool Accessibility Guidelines (ATAG)](https://www.w3.org/WAI/standards-guidelines/atag/).

This would mean (among others) that you

- Make it possible to provide an alternative text for users that upload photos to [Ensure that accessible content production is possible](https://www.w3.org/TR/ATAG20/#gl_b21)
- [Assist authors with managing alternative content for non-text content](https://www.w3.org/TR/ATAG20/#gl_b23)
- Provide an error or warning if alt is missing, to [Assist authors in checking for accessibility problems](https://www.w3.org/TR/ATAG20/#gl_b31)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a screen reader user myself, and I would vote for #1, or maybe #3, depending on the situation.

Your #4, no alt text, is in any case the worst one. Many screen readers render images without alt by giving the file name or even the full URL. It is always a totally useless annoyance.

Your #2, a generic alt text like "User uploaded content" is better, but if there are more than a few images in a row, less experienced users may think that they have reached the bottom of the page, or that the screen reader and/or the website are buggy.
For more advanced users, it's anyway no useful information.

Your #3, a generic alt text with indices like "Photo 1", "Photo 2", "Photo 3", "Photo 4", etc. is better than #2. Since the alt text differs by their indices, you can't think that you have reached the end of the page or that something is buggy.
It's still no useful information.

However, I think that the best of your solutions is #1, an empty alt text. 
Since the images provide anyway no useful information, they are better entirely skipped. In practice, that's what we do everyday when such such images are present.

There is one case where I would recommand #3 instead of #1 though: if you can do some action by clicking on the images.
IN this case, the empty alt text would prevent a screen reader user from launching the action. Image links, buttons and other actionnable elements must always have a non-empty alt text.

Another case when #3 might be useful is if I'm myself the author of the content. IN that case I might want to check if my images have correctly been uploaded and inserted where I want them to appear.

IN all other cases, I would go for #1, for the reasons explained above.

Of course, the real best solution would be to allow users  to give an alt text while they edit their content, and educate them about it.
You may argue that it's a description and that it would help them finding back their images; very useful if you give access to a place where they can see all what they have uploaded on the site in a single page, or if you allow them to upload images in advance.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say to put it like this:

```
alt="Image of {product}, uploaded by {user}"
```

It says what product is in the image, and that is was uploaded by a user.

Comment: We don't have the user name in this context to show. We could name the product out. But wouldn't that be repetitive if there were multiple images being read out as "Image of product"?

Comment: Yea I don’t think AI to analyze these photos is feasible for this case unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

assuming that you are building an dynamic web-app you can attept the try of Tobias and insert dynamic content in the alt tag. otherwise i think you have to stick at solution 2) since you cant dynamize content in html.

Comment: We have context as to what the product name is. But nothing else really related to the image that would be worthwhile showing. Does it really make sense to show multiple images with the same alt tag "Image of Product uploaded by customer"? This could be repetitive if read out 5-10 times no?

Comment: normally you dont see the alt tag but depending on your website it can have a bad impact on your seo. since you are running a shop(?) its recommended to use individual alt tags. unfortunately you dont store usernames or other data which you could individualize the alt tags.

Comment: I'm concerned less about SEO in this specific case than I am accessibility. I want screen readers to have the best experience. My concern is that they will be getting repetitive content of little use read out to them.

Comment: why not using a generic alt-tag combined with the file-name of the images? `Image of foobar: {file-name}`.

Comment: After upload the filenames become hashes, ex: `b127bas873ba.jpg`. So I don't think those being read out would be of any use.

Comment: it would fix the problem of repetetive content. do you have any other values you can insert instead?

Comment: I don't think a random hash fixes the problem of repetitive content. It just adds random jibberish to the repetitive content. I think ideally I would want content specific to that image I can tie it to. But I only have the name of the product and that I know it was uploaded content. Nothing else. I was under the impression repetitive content was not great for accessibility but I could be wrong. It's difficult to find hard and fast rules to this.

Comment: to evaulate which solution is the best you just have to analyze the given facts: 1. you cant add hashes 2. you cant add user related content since there is none 3. you cant add generic static content since that wouldnt solve your problem of repetetiveness. your problem is either not solvable or there is information missing to me.